# zurb foundation 4: Bullets won't center align in Chrome and IE9/IE10

Tags: zurb-foundation

Ok.. So I've checked (to the best of my abilities) in the issue list, but haven't found anything similar.. If there is an answer out there, apologies about adding a duplicate...

I am using the Foundation 4 framework, with the latest version.

I have bullets (UL mostly) at a lot of places. However, When I use `text-align: center` for any text with a bulleted list, the normal text and the list text is center aligned, but the bullets themselves (square, disc and so on) are not.

Now the weird part.... this issue occurs **only** in Chrome and IE9/IE10. It works as intended on Firefox / Safari. I've also tried using the `.text-center` class (part of foundation.css) which essentially does the same thing i.e., `text-align: center`.

Here's the test link http://www.crevolve.com/testing/ ....

Any help is much appreciated... Thank you...

Answer (score 6):

> I have bullets (UL mostly) at a lot of places. However, When I use
>   text-align: center for any text with a bulleted list, the normal text
>   and the list text is center aligned, but the bullets themselves
>   (square, disc and so on) are not.

You need to set the `list-style-position` of your `ul`, that by default has a value of `outside`. It means that the bullets will be outside the content flow ([read more about it here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/list-style-position)).

To solve your issue you can do this:

```
ul.square {
    list-style-position: inside;
    list-style-type: square;          
    text-align:center;
}
```

But hang on **that will NOT totally solve your issue**, I think, because if you have different length of texts in your `ul` then everything will be centered. That means they will not be aligned and it will not look good. [Look at the first slide on this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CHq7Z/) to see what I mean.

To have it centered and make it look good you can do the following:

```
.container {
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    right:50%;
    background-color:lightgreen;
}
.inner-container {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    background-color:lightyellow;
}
ul.square {  
    list-style-type: square;              
    width:300px;
}

<div> /* the wrapper div */
    <div class="container"> /* outer container to offset by 50% */
        <div class="inner-container"> /* inner container to make it center */
            <ul class="square">
                <li>First Item</li>
                <li>Second Item, this is a longer text</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The working sample is on slide 2 of the sampled jsfiddle. I included a background color so you can better see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the display of list-style-position: outside, while being able to center you bullet and list content on Chrome:

```
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
ul {
    padding-left: 11px;
    text-indent: -11px;
}
li {
    margin-left: -11px;
}
```

Downside: 11px is the width of the space bewteen the begining of the bullet and the begining of the text of your li. It's an ugly magic number, that may vary from one browser to another. Il haven't found any way to rationalize it, unfortunately...